# How do I remove empty <p> tags from a string using JavaScript or Cheerio?

Tags: javascript, html, tags, cheerio

I have some HTML as a string

```
"<p>This is a slightly longer post about something. Let's see how long this lasts. Okay so this is one paragraph now. </p><p>​</p><p>Let's write another paragraph, and see how it renders when I read this post later. </p><p>​</p><p>This is another short paragraph</p>"
```

How do I strip the empty p tags from this string using Cheerio or JS.

I've tried searching on Stack Overflow and Google in general without a clear working solution.

EDIT: Apologies, I have just noticed that my string has quite a lot of white space between the tags:

Here's an example one that comes up when I use console.log in my app:

```
<p>This is a slightly longer post about something. Let's see how long this lasts. Okay so this is one paragraph now. </p>
<p>​</p>
<p>Let's write another paragraph, and see how it renders when I read this post later. </p>
<p>​</p>
<p>Let's write another paragraph, and see how it renders when I read this post later. </p>
```

Comment: Does the <p> tag have any attributes?

Comment: it doesn't unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code in the empty `<p>` tags you have \u200b (Zero width space) characters. This character stay invisible but is there

You can use `split()` and `join('')` methods

```js
var test = "<p>This is a slightly longer post about something. Let's see how long this lasts. Okay so this is one paragraph now. </p><p>​</p><p>Let's write another paragraph, and see how it renders when I read this post later. </p><p>​</p><p>This is another short paragraph</p>";

var str = test.split('<p>​</p>').join('');

console.log(str);
```

Or you can use `replace()` method

```js
var test = "<p>This is a slightly longer post about something. Let's see how long this lasts. Okay so this is one paragraph now. </p><p>​</p><p>Let's write another paragraph, and see how it renders when I read this post later. </p><p>​</p><p>This is another short paragraph</p>";

var str = test.replace(/<p>​<\/p>/gi, '');

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I ended up needing to use .trim() before using the .replace on the string as I realised there were a few extra spaces, but this worked like a dream.

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace string `"<p></p>"` to empty string `""`

```js
var str = "<p>This is a slightly longer post about something. Let's see how long this lasts. Okay so this is one paragraph now. </p><p></p><p>Let's write another paragraph, and see how it renders when I read this post later. </p><p></p><p>This is another short paragraph</p>";

str = str.replace(/<p>\s*<\/p>/ig, '');
str = str.replace(/<p\s*\/>/ig, '');

console.log(str);
```

Comment: @NikhilVijayan I changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.replace("<p></p>", "")` if the tags don't have any attributes but if they do there is another way (aside from using regex to catch and replace tags).

A good way of doing things would be using native DOM functions.

To remove empty tag it is possible to use the following selector.

```
document.querySelectorAll("*:empty").forEach((x)=>{x.remove()});
```

In Your case maybe something like this

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "<p>hello there</p><p class='empty'></p><p>Not empty</p><p></p>"//your variable containing HTML here;
div.querySelectorAll("*:empty").forEach((x)=>{x.remove()})
// Output: div.innerHTML == <p>hello there</p><p>Not empty</p>
//Then use remaining innerHTML as you wish
```

But note that `:empty` will not work with whitespace like this `<p> </p>`
Also note that `:empty` will remove self closing tags

Answer (score 0):

We can match all spaces by using the regular expression **`/ {0,}/g`.** And we can add a **prefix** and **suffix** to this regular expression, in this case, it is a **p** tag.

Let's learn how to remove all **multiple spaces** from the text first.

```js
const text = "Some text             with          long    spaces"; 

const clearText = text.replace(/ {2,}/g, ' ');

console.log(clearText);
```

Let's apply the same principle to **empty p tag.**

```js
const result = "<p>   </p>  <p>   some   </p>".replace(/\<p> {0,}<\/p>/g, '');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```js
let str = "<p>This is a slightly longer post about something. Let's see how long this lasts. Okay so this is one paragraph now. </p><p></p><p>Let's write another paragraph, and see how it renders when I read this post later. </p><p></p><p>This is another short paragraph</p>";

// If your <p> element has attribtues then also it will be replaced.
str = str.replace(/<p(\s+[a-z0-9\-_\'\"=]+)*><\/p>/ig, '');

console.log(str);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%!important; top: 0;}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `replace` method:

```
str = "<p>This is some HTML code</p>";
stripped = str.replace("<p>", "").replace("<\/p>", "");

console.log(stripped);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I only want to take out empty <p> tags,, i.e. <p></p> but your answer strips off all <p> tags.

Comment: My bad, then try this: `str.replace("<p><\/p>", "")`

Answer (score -1):

```
const regex = /<[^>]*>\s*<\/[^>]*>/;
const str = `<p>This is a slightly longer post about something. Let's see how long this lasts. Okay so this is one paragraph now</p><p></p><p>Let's write another paragraph, and see how it renders when I read this post later. </p><p></p><p>This is another short paragraph</p>`;
let m;

 if ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
   // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
       console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
      });
```

Try This

Answer (score -1):

I used this:

```
function removeEmtpyElements(str, iterations){
    var re = /<([A-z]+)([^>^/]*)>\s*<\/\1>/gim;
    var subst = '';
    
    for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
        str = str.replace(re, subst);
    }
    
    return str;
}
```

Link: https://gist.github.com/Raz0rwire/838b918424c24dd5e592